# SPFX Angular *ngFor not working with routing

Tags: spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, angularjs, typescript

Iam using Angular project from Sahil Malik's blog [Use SPFx with Angular and Angular CLI](https://winsmarts.com/use-spfx-with-angular-cli-3747c306244b) as a startup solution/project....

And i implemented "@angular/router" for routing with some test pages.
[image]

Just for testing purpose i added some dummy data and html table for rendering the data on page1. But for some reason data never get rendered by *ngFor and in console i can see that there are 5 items in array.
[image]

For testing further i added same code in "app.component.ts" and "app.component.html" instead. 
And for some reason *ngFor works fine, table get rendered. But Why dosent it work on page1 ?!

By debugging in chrome i can see that table are rendered in html for "app.component.html", but table on page1 is not rendered or displaying...?!
[image]

It appears that there is something missing on page1 that makes ngFor not rendering the data on page. Here is html code snippit from chrome debub console:
[image]

Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/gonadn/SPFxAngularCLIWithRouting) for testing the solution...

Any help will be appriciated...Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Hello according to your github repo

You are missing to import Page1Component in appmodule.ts.
register your page1 component in **appmodule.ts** like:

```
import { Page1Component   } from './Page1/Page1Component';
```

**And in declaration in @NgModule**

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
AppComponent,
Page1Component,   
routingComponents
]
```

Hope will work for you

Comment: Thanks for answering #Sunil, but did you check "app.route.module.ts" under "app" folder? there i have import Page1Component registered as a route, and "app.route.module.ts" is registered in app.module.ts file....so all of my pages are registered in app.route.module.ts....!  In my app.module.ts i have under declarations: routingComponents...

Comment: The import for app.route.module is for referring component that you want to use in routing. Try referring them in app module.

Comment: Oki, i tryied refering all components in app.module.ts file as you explained, but dident help....Still i can see data rendered on app.component.html, table are displaying data, but not on page1....

Answer (score 0):

Page1, Page2 and Page 3 are registered under : routingComponents

[image]